# how can i assign arraylists to an array using oop?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, arraylist, assign

there is a bug in this code that I can't assign an array list to an array using oop and I can't find out how to fix it!
I'll put my code and classes down here to see anyone can help me to find out the issue!!!

```
package java808session06app04classnumber03;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Java808session06app04classnumber03 {


public static void main(String[] args) {


    final int SCHOOL_CLASS_NUMBER = 3;

    Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);

    SchoolClass[] schoolClassArray = new SchoolClass[SCHOOL_CLASS_NUMBER];

    int intNextStudent = 1;
    int intAvg = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < SCHOOL_CLASS_NUMBER; i++) {
        System.out.println("Class " + (i + 1) + ": ");

        do {
            ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
            Student st01 = new Student();
            System.out.print("Enter student name: ");
            st01._name = user.next();
            System.out.print("Enter student family: ");
            st01._family = user.next();
            System.out.print("Enter student grade01: ");
            st01._grade01 = user.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter student grade02: ");
            st01._grade02 = user.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter student grade03: ");
            st01._grade03 = user.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter student grade04: ");
            st01._grade04 = user.nextInt();

            studentList.add(st01);

            System.out.print("Is next student (1 for next student): ");
            intNextStudent = user.nextInt();


            schoolClassArray[i].studentList = studentList;
        } while (intNextStudent == 1);

    } 
  }
}
```

these are classes that I made for this code!

class SchoolClass

```
{
ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

class Student

```
{
String _name;
String _family;
int _grade01;
int _grade02;
int _grade03;
int _grade04;
 }
```

Comment: Hi, what are you intending to do in the line schoolClassArray[i].studentList = studentList;?

Answer (score 3):

You’ve forgotten to initialise a `SchoolClass` in your array.

Right after

```
for (int i = 0; i < SCHOOL_CLASS_NUMBER; i++) {
```

insert a line:

```
schoolClassArray[i] = new SchoolClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do in the code u provided. tho I see 1 potential error in your code, at the start of your `do` loop, you are creating a new `ArrayList` on each iteration, so you should move that out of the do loop.
and for the `ArrayList` to `Array` part you can do something similar to this ([Source](https://viralpatel.net/blogs/convert-arraylist-to-arrays-in-java/)):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("India");
list.add("Switzerland");

String [] countries = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```